# GuzzleHttp in Laravel and Cookies

Tags: php, http, cookies, guzzle

I have cookies content in a variable like the following:

```
$cookie = $res->getHeader('Set-Cookie')[0];
=> "mobrain_api=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; expires=Sun, 12-May-2019 06:25:33 GMT; Max-Age=86400; path=/; httponly"
```

I want to pass this string to Guzzle client for auth like on this image:

[image]

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass it to a CookieJar as is, as [described in the docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#cookies):

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\SetCookie;

$client = new Client();

$jar = new CookieJar();
$jar->setCookie(SetCookie::fromString($cookie));
$client->request('GET', '/v1/campaign/feed', ['cookies' => $jar]);
```

Comment: Returns {401: Access denied} from their API. In curl - call with the same credentials gets the correct response.